# How to form this MYSQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table

`TABLE store`

```
store   name   level
1       Tom    4
2       Joe    2
1       Chris  4
3       Tom    2
4       Ed     2
2       Tom    4
3       Chris  2
```

I want to return the number of level 4's from each distinct store
I know I can

```
select distinct store from store;
```

To get distinct stores and

```
select count(*) as level from store where level = 4;
```

to get the count of level 4's

How do I combine to return a query of number of level 4's in each distinct store
So the data above would return

```
store    level4
1        2
2        1
3        0
4        0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear why your table is called `store`.  Shouldn't you have a table with that name that has one row per store?

In any case, probably the simplest method for getting the `0` counts is conditional aggregation:

```
select store, sum(level = 4) as level4
from store
group by store;
```